# how to detect if user click "yes or no" on set homepage model window in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched in internet in most of the places were they says we can't detect the click in set homepage model window . But when I saw yahoo site http://www.yahoo.com/bin/set? they are actually detecting if the user as set the homepage or not .

If homepage is set they are showing a message that you have already set the page .

My questions :

1) Is there a way to detect it ? if any script/jquery can anyone help me here?
2) how yahoo is detecting this?

Answer (score 2):

I bet Yahoo's solution works only in IE. IE offers a feature called behaviors and the default behavior set has a **homePage** behavior. You can use that for setting a homepage, navigating to a homepage and checking if a page is a home page.

Check the example code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms531418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx